# Identify lines using grep or similar UNIX command on a sorted file not containing specific attributes

Tags: unix, sed, grep

### Input "sample.txt"

```
1234 Bob   10 A
1234 Bob   20 B
1235 John  10 C
1236 Jim   10 A
1236 Jim   20 R
1237 Tom   20 A
1238 Jane  10 B
1238 Jane  20 D
1238 Jane  24 R
```

### Goal find lines that don't have a '10' record at a specific position

```
$ grep '^...........10' sample.txt
1234 Bob   10 A
1235 John  10 C
1236 Jim   10 A
1238 Jane  10 B
```

### Now pull out the account numbers of just the 'good' ones

```
$ grep  '^...........10' sample.txt | cut -b 1-5
1234
1235
1236
1238
```

### Question:  How to feed this account number list as patterns to sed or something similar to produce a file that no longer has:

```
1237 Tom   20 A
```

Even more interesting would be to manufacture a '10' dummy record so that the account is 'good':

```
1237 Tom   10 Dummy
1237 Tom   20 A
```

Comment: Er... if you want records with the third column equal to 10, why not awk? `awk '$3 == 10' sample.txt` is a lot clearer than that grep.

Comment: You mean you want to compare one file's values with another ones? Could you please do clearly add samples of expected output in your post please as it's not clear.

Comment: Also you say *Goal find lines that don't have a '10' record at a specific position* but then list just the lines that do?

Comment: Please elaborate more on line `Even more interesting would be to manufacture a '10' dummy record so that the account is 'good'`  too it is not at all clear like by which conditions and where you want to insert a dummy record too? Along with other questions.

Comment: Could you please check my solution once and lemme know if that helped you?

Answer (score 1):

So, I *think* you want all groups of records from your original file that include at least one record of each group of with a 10 in the third column?

One way, using `join`:

```
$ join -o 0,2.2,2.3,2.4 -j1 <(awk '$3 == 10 { print $1 }' sample.txt | uniq) sample.txt
1234 Bob 10 A
1234 Bob 20 B
1235 John 10 C
1236 Jim 10 A
1236 Jim 20 R
1238 Jane 10 B
1238 Jane 20 D
1238 Jane 24 R
```

(Notes: This requires bash, zsh, or another shell that understands `<(command)` redirection).

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to remove those Lines which group by $1(first field) whose 3rd field doesn't have 10 in any of the lines then try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{if($3==10){a[$1]};next} ($1 in a)' Input_file Input_file
```